# how to query with out [0] in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'd like to make a query that moves ytbReqTb's data to ytbChannelTb.

This is my Schema(ytbReqTb)

```
const ytbReqTbSchema = new Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ytbChannel: String,
    ytbSubscribe: Number,
    ytbHits: Number
}
```

and this is my other Schema(ytbChannelTb).

```
{
    const ytbChannelTbSchema = new Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ytbChannel: String,
    ytbSubscribe: Number,
    ytbHits: Number,
}
```

So I query like this and it works.

```
router.put('/recognize/:youtuber', async (req, res, next) => {

    const ytbReq = await YtbReqTb.find({ 'ytbChannel' : req.params.youtuber });

    await YtbReqTb.remove({ 'ytbChannel' : req.params.youtuber });

    const ytbChannelTb = new YtbChannelTb({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        ytbChannel: ytbReq[0].ytbChannel,
        ytbSubscribe: ytbReq[0].ytbSubscribe,
        ytbHits: ytbReq[0].ytbHits,
    });
    ytbChannelTb.save()
    .then(result => {
        res.status(201).json();
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
            error: err
        });
    });
});
```

But it doesn't work without '[0]'. Is there a way to query without '[0]'?

If query can't take out '[0]', could you tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the result of find is a array, if you want result be an object so use `findOne` instead of `find` like this:

```
const ytbReq = await YtbReqTb.findOne({ 'ytbChannel' : req.params.youtuber });
```

Comment: Thank you for your help
I can resolve this with your help :)